# Imagick rendering a black image

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to convert a SVG into PNG but I'm having trouuble with it.

With this link you can upload a SVG and the file will show the result:
http://clound.com.br/labs/svg/export/imagick/index.php

The SVG that I'm trying to upload is this:
http://clound.com.br/labs/svg/export/images/cover.svg

My code on the upload page is this:

```
<?php
if ( $_FILES ){
$target_path = 'output/'. basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
$mime = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'];

if ( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] ){
    die( 'Error on upload.');
}

if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path ) ){
    echo '<embed style="border:solid 1px gray;" src="'.$target_path.'" type="image/svg+xml" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/" /><br / >';


    $im = new Imagick();
    $svg = file_get_contents($target_path);

    /*loop to color each state as needed, something like*/ 
    $dom = new DOMDocument(); 
    $dom->loadXML( $svg ); 

    removeFillRule($dom, 'g');
    removeFillRule($dom, 'mask');
    removeFillRule($dom, 'path');
    removeFillRule($dom, 'image');

    $svg = $dom->saveXML();
    echo $svg;

    $im->readImageBlob($svg);

    /*png settings*/
    $im->setImageFormat("png32");
    $im->writeImage('output/image.png');/*(or .jpg)*/
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();

    echo '<img src="output/image.png"/><br/>';
}
else
{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, verify permission and try again!";
}
}




function remove_children(&$node) {
while ($node->firstChild) {
while ($node->firstChild->firstChild) {
  remove_children($node->firstChild);
}
$node->removeChild($node->firstChild);
}
}


function removeFillRule($dom, $element){
$path = $dom->getElementsByTagName($element);
foreach ($path as  $key=> $value) {
    $path->item($key)->removeAttribute('fill-rule');
}
}
```

My version on server is this:

> ImageMagick 6.7.6-8 2012-05-02 Q16 `http://www.imagemagick.org`

Comment: And do you have an error or something else?

Comment: No, you can try to upload the images that i've posted on the link...
i think that have something wrong with my SVG source code... It was generated by BonsaiJS but if you try to save this image http://clound.com.br/labs/svg/export/images/cover.svg it doesn't show nothing...

Comment: I tried your code with this svg file http://www.w3schools.com/svg/circle1.svg get error from  function removeChild() where you use it?

Comment: I've removed the code that was removing defs tag which was giving the error. Try to upload again, as you will see, the red circle will be upload and my cover will still be a black image.

Answer (score 0):

Removing fill-rule? That will break some svgs, just saying. I'm curious, is that a workaround for some bug in imagemagick?

Anyway, a guess is that your issue is that imagemagick probably doesn't support rgba-syntax in fill/stroke - which would make the fill black by default.

Comment: The fill rule it's because the SVG rendered by bonsaijs has a default fill rule that was making imagick not render it right... I will try to convert the colors as you said and see what happens, thank you for the help.

Comment: You can convert `fill=rgba(29,35,12,0.4)` into the tuple `fill="rgb(29,35,12)"`, `fill-opacity="0.4"`. In your file you have many examples where the alpha component is either 1 or 0, which makes it even simpler.